# Store Data in a TabControl?

Tags: vb.net

I'm new to the whole tab control, and was wondering if there was any way possible to store data in a tab control. What I mean by this is storing a Boolean or int for each tab control, so when the selected tab index is changed, it enables a button for example off the Boolean for every tab. How can I accomplish this? (By the way my tab control has a new tab function, so it creates a new tab with a click of a button)

Comment: I think you mean `TabPage` not the `TabControl` itself. The answer is yes. You need to inherit the tabpage and then and a property with the Boolean type. Another option is create a list that would house these tabs and their state. You then can do what you need with each. On another note, what have you tried so far? Please show us first and then we can help.

Comment: I think there is a [Tag](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.control.tag%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) property in Tab Page where you can store an object.

Answer (score -1):

Maybe something like this will work for you..

```
Public Class Form1

    Private Sub TabControl_SelectedIndexChanged(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles TabControl.SelectedIndexChanged
        Select Case Me.TabControl.SelectedIndex

            Case 0
                Me.Button1.Enabled = True
                Me.Button2.Enabled = False
            Case 1
                Me.Button1.Enabled = False
                Me.Button2.Enabled = True

        End Select
    End Sub

End Class
```